# Apache version in XAMPP

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

I'm trying to figure out which version of Apache is on the latests XAMPP builds ( 1.8.2-5 and 1.8.3-4 ).

I've checked the XAMPP website, tried googling the question and browsed through the folders on my XAMPP install to try to find a readme or something.

Comment: It is generally v2.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run in command line

```
<xampp_dir>\apache\bin\httpd -v
```

It prints Apache version.

For example I had installed XAMPP to `C:\Aplikace\xampp` directory and type into Command Line

```
C:\Aplikace\xampp\apache\bin\httpd -v
```

that responsed

[image: Apache version output]

Answer (score 0):

- Go to xampp folder where you installed xampp
- Find apache?
- xampp->apache->bin->httpd->right click->properties->details->version 
  find php version in xampp
- xampp control panel which, after the complete installation, contains start, stop, config, etc.
- There you find shell-> click->type php-v
- mariaDB version in xampp?
- Type localhost/phpmyadmin after installation on url
- Find sql
- Type select version(); and hit enter

Comment: I did a little formatting and cleanup, but I'm not familiar enough with this to make it clear.  Can you make it a little more explicit and flesh it out a little with some sentences?